# How to debug MVC6 with Mono and vscode on OSX?

Tags: macos, mono, visual-studio-code

I've looked through a bunch of websites including the main code.visualstudio.com website, and here of course, and I've seen a bunch of things that almost answer this question, but nothing quite.

I'm running a(n) MVC6 app, using VSCode/mono/OSX, and I want to debug. [This post](http://schlapsi.com/2015/05/debugging-mono-applications-with-vscode-on-mac-os-x/) describes what to put in the config file, but it says `<path to executable file>`, which...is the part I don't know. What/where is the binary I'm supposed to point to in the config file?

Thanks for any help you can offer.